# Error while setting Up Ehcahe 3 with spring boot 1.5

Tags: caching, spring-boot, spring-4, jcache, ehcache-3

I have recently upgraded to spring boot 1.5.7 from 1.4 and found that Ehcache has been upgraded to 3.x from 2.x. The configurations have all changed. Now I am unable to set up the caching config.

I tried following the steps on the official [blog](http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/18/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html) at Ehcache but no success.

Here is my `ehcache-dev.xml`

```
<config
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:jcache='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>

    <service>
        <jcache:defaults>

            <jcache:cache name="categoryCache" template="catalog-cache"/>
            <jcache:cache name="cfCategoryCache" template="catalog-cache"/>

            <jcache:cache name="ebooks" template="other-cache"/>
            <jcache:cache name="userNameToken" template="other-cache"/>

        </jcache:defaults>
    </service>

    <cache-template name="catalog-cache">
        <heap unit="entries">200</heap>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
        </expiry>
    </cache-template>

    <cache-template name="other-cache">
        <!--<listeners>-->
        <!--<listener>-->
        <!--<class>org.terracotta.ehcache.EventLogger</class>-->
        <!--<event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>-->
        <!--<event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>-->
        <!--<events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>-->
        <!--<events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>-->
        <!--<events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>-->
        <!--<events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>-->
        <!--<events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>-->
        <!--</listener>-->
        <!--</listeners>-->
        <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="minutes">15</ttl>
        </expiry>
    </cache-template>
</config>
```

My `application-dev.properties` file contains the line:

`spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache-dev.xml`

While running on `dev` profile, It generates the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is javax.cache.CacheException: org.ehcache.xml.exceptions.XmlConfigurationException: Error parsing XML configuration at file:/**********/target/********/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-dev.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: org.ehcache.xml.exceptions.XmlConfigurationException: Error parsing XML configuration at file:/**********/target/********/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-dev.xml
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider$ConfigSupplier.getConfiguration(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:327)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:128)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.createCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.jCacheCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46f8ca07.CGLIB$jCacheCacheManager$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46f8ca07$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fee1b5ae.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46f8ca07.jCacheCacheManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: org.ehcache.xml.exceptions.XmlConfigurationException: Error parsing XML configuration at file:/**********/target/********/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-dev.xml
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:131)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider$ConfigSupplier.getConfiguration(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:324)
    ... 150 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/**********/target/********/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-dev.xml; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 17; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'expiry'. One of '{"http://www.ehcache.org/v3":heap-store-settings, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":disk-store-settings, "http://www.ehcache.org/v3":service-configuration}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    at org.ehcache.xml.ConfigurationParser.<init>(ConfigurationParser.java:165)
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.parseConfiguration(XmlConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:163)
    ... 152 more
```

Now, If I am not wrong, it has problem with accepting `expiry` element inside the `cache-template` element. But this should not be the case as it is clearly mentioned [here](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/xml.html) that `A <cache-template> element may contain all the same child elements as a <cache> element.` and `cache` element does have an `expiry` element.

I am unable to understand what am I missing here. Any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is in the order of elements.
The `heap` element needs to be after the `expiry` element.

The below configuration works alright:

```
 <cache-template name="catalog-cache">        
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">200</heap>
</cache-template>
```

This makes no sense as order should not matter. Have filed a [bug-report](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/2178) with EhCache

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to the XML example for version 3 (jsr107 extension) given in the ehcache documentation, see [link](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/examples.html#xml-with-107-extension). See if your XML format follows the tags given there.